# Why is MeteorJS having high event loop latency even in idle?

Tags: javascript, meteor, pm2

After I deployed a tiny app on my VPS using PM2, I quickly saw that the app was doing "something" in idle, but I thought it perhaps had something to do with the startup process. But a few hours later, and the latency is still pretty high for a computing standpoint.

[image]

**Note**: At the time I am pointing in the capture, I was hitting refresh on the browser a few times, and the time varies between 8.45ms to 8.52ms.

Any idea why this is so?

Comment: Do you mean by `tiny` a newly created project without packages (like meteor create --bare) or a project with just a few lines of your code?

Comment: a project with 3 routes and a single collection

Comment: Would you mind adding the code if it's compact enough?

Comment: It isn't. But the latency is at that value even if there are no activities whatsoever (i.e. no subscription and no connected user).

Comment: So it should happen on a newly created project without any additional code?

Comment: I would have to create another VPS and deploy it with pm2 meteor, then? I was hoping to know if this is a normal behavior for a MeteorJS project to have this latency.